# Apply different stylesheets for both Android and iPhone

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am building **`HTML5`** apps for both `Android` and `iPhone` using `phonegap` and `jquery mobile.`

Is it possible to apply different style sheets for `iOS` and `Android.`

How can i include style sheets after detecting particular OS.

The following is my `javascript` code:

```
var deviceType = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))  == "iPad" ? "iPad" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))  == "iPhone" ? "iPhone" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) == "Android" ? "Android" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) == "BlackBerry" ? "BlackBerry" : "null";
```

Comment: hi i thnk we can use the above code and detect OS and change css on deviceready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using what you have, you can add the found `deviceType` as a class to the body tag.

---

**JavaScript**

```
var deviceType = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))  == "iPad" ? "iPad" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))  == "iPhone" ? "iPhone" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) == "Android" ? "Android" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) == "BlackBerry" ? "BlackBerry" : "null";
$("body").addClass(deviceType);
```

**CSS**

The code below is an example for styling a div that is read by the different devices.

```
div {
    /* general style for a div */
}
.iPhone div {
    /* style for a div in iPhone (will be override the general style) */
}
.Android div {
    /* style for a div in Android (will be override the general style) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple:

```
$('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', 'your_stylesheet_url.css') );
```

or `document.createStyleSheet('your_stylesheet_url.css');`